# Beamerarticle generates Undefined control sequence

Tags: beamer, report, undefined

I generate a report including all of my beamer slides from all my lectures. In an attempt to clean up the (vertical) spacing in the notes I redefined frame as follows:

```
\renewenvironment{frame}{\ignorespaces}{\ignorespacesafterend}
```

That yields an error whenever I use `\frametitle` (versus `\begin{frame}{The Title}`)

The short-term fix is to just put up with the spacing issues. Is this the best I can do? MWE follows

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}

% Following line causes the trouble % % % % % %
\renewenvironment{frame}{\ignorespaces}{\ignorespacesafterend}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

\begin{document}

\mode<all>
\section{Price Instruments}

\begin{frame}{Fees Reconsidered}

\begin{description}
\item[Environmental Tax Reform (ETR)]  introducing
fees and reducing  income or corporate taxes

\item[double dividend] besides reducing emissions, the reduction in
other taxes is likely to partially\footnote{But not completely.}
offset the negative consequences of the fee on the economy.
\end{description}

\end{frame}
\mode*

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Fees Reconsidered}

\begin{description}
\item[Environmental Tax Reform (ETR)]  introducing
fees and reducing  income or corporate taxes

\item[double dividend] besides reducing emissions, the reduction in
other taxes is likely to partially\footnote{But not completely.}
offset the negative consequences of the fee on the economy.
\end{description}

\end{frame}

\mode*

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The frame environment is a central element in beamer, which e.g. activates all kinds of beamer specific macros like `\frametitle`. If you redefine the frame environment, you won't be able to use them.

Instead you could use the `frame begin/end` templates to add whatever code you would like to execute at the start and end of a frame:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\setbeamertemplate{frame begin}{\vspace{-0.2cm}}
\setbeamertemplate{frame end}{\vspace{-0.2cm}}


\begin{document}

\section{Price Instruments}

\begin{frame}{Fees Reconsidered}

\begin{description}
\item[Environmental Tax Reform (ETR)]  introducing
fees and reducing  income or corporate taxes

\item[double dividend] besides reducing emissions, the reduction in
other taxes is likely to partially\footnote{But not completely.}
offset the negative consequences of the fee on the economy.
\end{description}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Fees Reconsidered}

\begin{description}
\item[Environmental Tax Reform (ETR)]  introducing
fees and reducing  income or corporate taxes

\item[double dividend] besides reducing emissions, the reduction in
other taxes is likely to partially\footnote{But not completely.}
offset the negative consequences of the fee on the economy.
\end{description}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```